# html input field set range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

What is the most efficient way to set the range for an input-field to -100.0 to 100.0? I would like to check every character. Other characters than -,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and . are not allowed. Values without floating point, e.g. 78, are also possible.

**UPDATE**

I need a solution for IE, so html5 solution with type="range" or type="number" are useless for me.
The only code I have is the input field:

```
<input type="text" id="zahlenwert" value="" />
```

The question is: Do I have to check every character with onKeydown() or is there a smarter way?

Comment: what code have you got so far?

Comment: You need to use a onkeyup function that will validate when some one is entering the data this way you can restrict the input field. Please put some sample code you worked on so that we can have a better idea and answer it.

Comment: “Most efficient”? Well, that would be [`<input type="range">`](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php), I’d say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I wanted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input#zahlenwert").keyup(function(){
    var zahlenwert= $("input#zahlenwert").val();
    var status = 0;

    for(i=zahlenwert.length;i>0;i--){
        if(status==0){
            if(zahlenwert.length == 0){
            }
            else if(zahlenwert.length == 1 && zahlenwert.match(/^(-|[0-9]) /)!=null){
                status = 1;
                console.log("zahlenwert ok");
            }
            else if(zahlenwert.length == 2 && zahlenwert.match(/^(-[0-9]|[0-9],|[1-9][0-9])/)!=null){
                status = 1;
                console.log("zahlenwert ok");
            }
            else if(zahlenwert.length == 3 && zahlenwert.match(/^(-[1-9][0-9]|[0-9],[0-9]|100|[1-9][0-9],|-[0-9],)/)!=null){
                status = 1;
                console.log("zahlenwert ok");
            }
            else if(zahlenwert.length == 4 && zahlenwert.match(/^(-100|100,|[1-9][0-9],[0-9]|-[0-9],[0-9]|-[1-9][0-9],)/)!=null){
                status = 1;
                console.log("zahlenwert ok");
            }
            else if(zahlenwert.length == 5 && zahlenwert.match(/^(100,0|-100,|-[1-9][0-9],[0-9])/)!=null){
                status = 1;
                console.log("zahlenwert ok");
            }
            else if(zahlenwert.length == 6 && zahlenwert.match(/^-100,0/)!=null){
                status = 1;
                console.log("zahlenwert ok");
            }
            else{
                zahlenwert = zahlenwert.substring(0,zahlenwert.length-1);
                $("input#zahlenwert").val(zahlenwert);
                console.log("Error!!!");
            }
        }
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for:

http://jeroenvanwarmerdam.nl/content/resources/javascript/jquery/spincontrol/jquery-spincontrol-1.0.zip

And here is example:

http://jeroenvanwarmerdam.nl/content/resources/javascript/jquery/spincontrol/jquery-spincontrol.html?x=31&y=10

Integration:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-numeric.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-number-selector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-spincontrol-support.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-spincontrol.js"></script>

<!-- SpinControl definition -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $(":number").addClass("number").spinControl({ folder: "images/" });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Here is your body html code:

```
<input type="number" max="10" min="-10" step="0.5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm partly guessing at your requirements but if you're just trying to restrict the input value to a number within a specific range you could use HTML5's [range input type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.range.html):

```
<input type="range" name="myrange" min="-100" max="100">
```

Or use JavaScript to validate the value like in [this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7t8Wz/):

```
document.getElementById('test').onchange = isNumber;
function isNumber(){
    var val = this.value;
    var aNumber = !isNaN(val);
    var aNumberNotOverOneHundred = (Math.abs(parseFloat(val, 10)) <= 100);
    alert((aNumber && aNumberNotOverOneHundred)?"Yarp":"Narp");
}
```

Or use [input pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) to validate against a regex pattern.